# pattern matching to detect special characters in a word

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to identify any special characters ('?', '.', ',') at the end of a string in java. Here is what I wrote:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("{.,?}$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Sure?");
    System.out.println("Input String matches regex - "+matcher.matches());

}
```

This returns a `false` when it's expected to be `true`. Please suggest.

Comment: Try square brackets instead of curly ones.

Comment: Use a site like http://erik.eae.net/playground/regexp/regexp.html to test and experiment with your regex.

Answer (score 3):

Use `"sure?".matches(".*[.,?]")`.

`String#matches(...)` anto-anchors the regex with `^` and `$`, no need to add them manually.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*[.,?]");
...
```

Comment: This will work if you use the `matches()` method (see [sp00m's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19998497/20938)), but if you use `find()` it will match if there's a `.`, `,` or `?` anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 2):

This is your code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("{.,?}$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Sure?");
System.out.println("Input String matches regex - "+matcher.matches());
```

You have 2 problems:

1. You're using `{ and }` instead of character class `[ and ]`
2. You're using `Matcher#matches()` instead of `Matcher#find`. `matches` method matches the full input line while `find` performs a search anywhere in the string.

Change your code to:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[.,?]$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Sure?");
System.out.println("Input String matches regex - " + matcher.find());
```